# Jetty SslConnector's deprecated methods

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, deprecated

[`SslConnector.java`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ssl/SslConnector.html) interface has been changed in the newest Jetty *7.3.1.v20110307*.

Almost all off the methods have been marked as deprecated without mentioning the replacement interface or methods to use.

I've checked  the [*jetty-users*](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/jetty-users) and [*jetty-dev*](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/jetty-dev) mailing lists for the information with no luck.

Is there anybody out there who knows how should be the code changed for the future?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, digging out from the subversion changelog for the corresponding commits (crazy) it came out that [`SslContextFactory`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.html) should be used.

*Example:*

```
final SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory(sKeyStore);
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(sPassword);

final SslSocketConnector conn = new SslSocketConnector(sslContextFactory);
conn.setReuseAddress(true);
// ...
```

Comment: And now SslContextFactory itself is deprecated... they sure love to change the API a lot at Jetty.

Comment: @Trejkaz it depends on which `SslContextFactory` you're importing.

Comment: all of the `SslContextFactory` constructors is deprecated, use either `SslContextFactory.Server()` or `SslContextFactory.Client()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Building on your own answer:

```java
Server server = new Server();

// Encrypt the connection using a valid certificate/keystore
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory("path/keystore.jks");
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");

// Create a new SocketConnector at port 443, which is the default port for
// HTTPS web pages (no port number needs to be specified in the browser).
SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector(sslContextFactory);
sslConnector.setPort(443);

// Add the SocketConnector to the server
server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {sslConnector});
```