# Avoid use of deprecated methods in org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector with jetty-maven-plugin

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

Releated to

- [Deprecated Embedded Jetty 7.6 using SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359429/deprecated-embedded-jetty-7-6-using-ssl)
- [Jetty SslConnector's deprecated methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220651/jetty-sslconnectors-deprecated-methods)

How to write correct Maven POM without using the deprecated methods / tags in connector like *needClientAuth* or *keystore*?

Example with deprecated method use:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin -->
        <version>8.0.4.v20111024</version>
        <!-- see http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mortbay.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-maven-plugin%22 -->
        <dependencies>
          <!--[...]-->
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <webAppXml>src/main/resources/jetty-Login.xml</webAppXml>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/MyApp</contextPath>
          </webAppConfig>
          <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
                <port>8080</port>
            </connector>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
                <port>8443</port>
                <password>changeit</password>
                <wantClientAuth>true</wantClientAuth><!-- deprecated! -->
                <needClientAuth>false</needClientAuth><!-- deprecated! -->
                <keystore>/my/path/to/java/keystore</keystore><!-- deprecated! -->
            </connector>
          </connectors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

A custom Ssl configuration via the maven configuration structure isn't possible.
This is due to the introduction of the SslContextFactory requirement on the SslSocketConnector constructor to tighten up some SSL security issues on the server side.

Maven can only construct objects from the default constructor when using the  structures in the pom.xml.

You'll have to bridge the change via the `<jettyXml>` element.
Go grab a copy of the [jetty-ssl.xml](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty-ssl.xml) from the distribution and put it into your ${project.basedir}/src/main/config/jetty-ssl.xml and use the following configuration block.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty-version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
      <webAppConfig>
        <contextPath>/MyApp</contextPath>
      </webAppConfig>
      <jettyXml>src/main/config/jetty-ssl.xml</jettyXml>
      <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
          <port>8080</port>
        </connector>
      </connectors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```